# Put symlink in a slow drive pointing to a NMVE is a good way to speed up docs loading?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, symbolic-link, performance-tuning

Cleaning up things after a MB crash, I got a Samsung NMVE 2 (1TB) drive and did transfered Windows 10 64 bits from a SATA SSD to it (in a 500GB partition), and really helped to load OS and some Apps, like Chrome with 20 tabs, for example.

Problem: for Visual Studio development solutions, Office (64) Docs and pdfs it did not help a lot...

I have 500GB available in another partition of Samsung NMVE 2, but My Documents folder has almost this size, and I really want to speed up only those cited above, that weight around 100GB. For several reasons I do not want to have a My Documents folder in two drives letters.

My Documents folder is located in a bigger and slower SATA 6 drive, NAS series, with 5600 RPM...

So, any tips, drawbacks, problems anticipated in this strategy: put symlinks in the original slow drive pointing to the faster NMVE? It will slow a lot the loading from NMVE?

Of course, any other strategy to suggest?

TIA

Comment: No, that's basically what I would do. If it is your entire My Documents drive, you can just go to properties, location, and change it there, then say move all files to do it for you. easier than symlinks

Comment: @LPChip: in this case I'll test both strategies in a couple folders and do a benchmark just to confirm that there is no strange result or discrepancy - who knows? - and I'll post here. Thanks.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I do.. only I use folder junctions and not symlinks.  I also do the opposite and put BIG JUNK (like symbols or rarely used sdks) on the slow drive and link back to the fast one to save precious FAST space.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: after your comment I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586946/2752308) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524980/2752308) but could not figure out one big reason to use folder junctions instead. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I read conflicting info on links above: one say that folder junctions do not functions with network shared folders;  [other](https://winaero.com/move-the-users-folder-in-windows-10-windows-8-and-windows-7/) says the opposite...

Comment: To be honest.. I have never used the network functionality.  I only use them as we are discussing here and I am old school.. symlinks are still new to windows from my perspective.  I would suggest experimenting ;)

Comment: OH.. also, @LPChip is a smart cookie (pun intended).. I also find that changing the actual directory the explorer will use is easier.  The only problem with this method is that SOME DEVS are too lazy or too stupid to ask the win32 API where the documents folder is located and make assumptions.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks :D mmmm cookies... :) And I agree, though in recent years I did not find any software that would get it wrong. The benefit of using explorer is that you can use a network path (as long as you have that path mapped to a drive letter) And symlinks *can* be linked to a network share as long as you use the /d parameter.

Comment: Over next week I´ll hope have time to test network share too, and will post here. Thanks, guys.